# SQL Project type is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm getting this message when i'm trying to open the solution, all projects are loaded properly except one (.sqlproj).
I have installed,
VS2010 SP1, Sql Server-2008 R2 SP1, MVC3, VS2010 SP1 Tools for SQL Server Compact 4.0 ENU

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this problem is resolve on installing VS-2012.

Answer (score 5):

.sqlproj is the extension for the project file used by SSDT (Sql Server Data Tools)

Therefore you need to install SSDT either from a SQL Server 2012 DVD or from Web Plattform

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

if you only need database support and no support for SSAS , SSIS and SSRS.
Newer versions of VS (2013 for sure) include this by default.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by installing "SQL Server Data Tools **2010**" via the Web Platform Installer.  I had the exact same error and don't see what VS2012 has to do with anything - there is nothing related to 2012 in any of the projects I'm working with.  SSDT is the key, but you want the version for your corresponding version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed VS2010. Then, I Installed VS 2012 and start to fail to open .sqlproj files. Then I downloaded **SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2010** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650014 and works again in VS2010.